# Thread affinity vs Process affinity

Tags: linux, multithreading, process, shared-memory, affinity

I have a latency sensitive application that consists of **2 logical** parts which can run in parallel. My original design is to make each logical part a standalone program and run them on separate cores passing information by **file mapped shared memory**. But after knowing that **even 2 threads from the same process can run in separate cores**, I'm think of merging the 2 programs into one process, each running on a **thread** tied to standalone core. And since all threads in a process share the memory space, I can eliminate the shared memory and use **program memory space** directly, which will be faster.

Is my reasoning correct? If correct, what's the advantage of separating an application into **processes** instead of using **thread affinity** in one process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes, your reasoning is correct. In Linux you can bind different threads with different cores, so you can get rid of **file mapped shared memory**.

2) **File mapped shared memory** (I would use the term **inter-process shared memory**) mostly serves as a way of communication/messaging between different processes, e.g. between a monitor process that needs to run in the background all the time, and a user interface process that can be opened/closed at any time. In your case, you only need thread affinity.